# PHP - Memory leak when fetching large tables from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

(Using pdo)

So I have a table which is almost 1 GB in size I want to fetch from. At the same time, I am manipulating the data I fetch and then inserting it into multiple other tables. My code looks something like this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM foo");

$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO bar (col1) VALUES (?)");
$stmt3 = //...etc

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $toInsert = doStuff($row['baz']);
    $stmt2->execute(array($toInsert));

    //etc.
}
```

Whenever I run the script on the full table, it runs out of memory. I could give it more, but I feel like there's a better way.

I think unbuffered queries would probably solve the issue, but I need to run these queries concurrently.

Comment: `INSERT INTO bar (col1) (SELECT baz FROM foo)`

Comment: Do batch processing, few 100 records at a time, make a log table in case something goes wrong with any specific row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could using an unbuffered query for the reading and setting up another PDO connection for your insert operations be a solution?

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I had tried this idea before on the same PDO object with this snippet of code:
`$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM $RawPDBData",array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => false));
$statement->execute();`

But this didn't work. Any idea why a new PDO object works but not this?

Comment: An unbuffered query is blocking the current (PDO) connection until the full result set is fetched from the (MySQL) server. This is why you cannot re-use the same connection concurrently and you have to use a second connection for the other queries.

Comment: To clarify, when I say it didn't work, I mean the code ran but still had memory leaks present. It acted as though the extra attribute I had passed to the prepare() did not even exist. Why did this not at least throw an error for subsequent concurrent queries?

Comment: Strange... from what you are writing, you should have received an error.

Answer (score 1):

When you read the data from the database and use it in PHP, The PHP object will take memory as well MySQL (for doing work and give you back the result).

Your query looks simple. You can write one statement which contains both queries. this way it will work without PHP memory issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try paginating with limit and offset

```
$limit = 1000;
$offset = 0;

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY id ACC LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset");

$hadResult = false;
do {
    $stmt->bindParam(':limit', $pageSize, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $hadResult = true;
        ///do stuff
    }
    $offset += $limit;
} while($hadResult);
```